# Define return parameter for select statement when nothing is found

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my select statement. What does it do?

- Check if there are already appointments in the database for the given date
- Check if the user is working at that specific time.

With `mysql_num_rows($result)` I check if there are any rows. If it returns 0, the appointment can be added, if it returns something else (there is already an appointment in the database) it is blocked.

The statement works for point 1. If there is already an appointment, it returns 1 or more. But it when the selected date is out of the working hour range of the user, then it also returns 0.

Question: What can I add to the statement to get a returned row (`mysql_num_rows` return 1 or more), when the user **is not working** at that specific time?

Example of working hour range: `08:00:00 to 17:00:00`.

```
select * 
from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk) 
where workerid_fk = 1 
AND h.start <= '19:57:20' AND h.end >= '20:57:20' 
AND ( 
   a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
   OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
   OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 19:57:20' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 20:57:20') 
)
```

Comment: use `case` to validate if any number of rows returned or not.

Comment: Mysql has supported [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) for some time now.

Comment: Why is this tagged pl/sql?

Comment: Two things - the use of `BETWEEN` should be avoided in favor of using exclusive upper-bounds (`<` - consider, when a work shift ends at `17:00`, they've actually clocked out by that time, they aren't still working for the first second/millisecond/whatever), and this isn't robust enough for a 'highly' concurrent environment (is that going to be a concern?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a row of nulls:

```
select * 
from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk) 
where workerid_fk = 1 
AND h.start <= '19:57:20' AND h.end >= '20:57:20' 
AND ( 
   a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
   OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
   OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 19:57:20' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 20:57:20') 
)
union
select null, null, null -- how every many column are in the first part
where not exists (
    select * 
    from ios_appointments a join ios_workinghours h using(workerid_fk) 
    where workerid_fk = 1 
    AND h.start <= '19:57:20' AND h.end >= '20:57:20' 
    AND ( 
       a.start BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
       OR  a.end   BETWEEN '2012-12-24 19:57:20'  AND  '2012-12-24 20:57:20' 
       OR (a.start < '2012-12-24 19:57:20' AND a.end > '2012-12-24 20:57:20') 
    )
)
```

This returns one row of nulls if your query find nothing, or behaves as now if rows are found.

Instead of nulls you could return any values you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem with this statement is that it now returns a null row each time when no appointment is found. I only need a null row, when the time is outside the working hours time. Any idea for this?

Comment: Afaik there's no such thing as a null row. Can't you use your application layer (php?) to check the number of rows in the result set?